# Add event listener to dynamically created button

Tags: javascript

I browsed the other answers but couldn't find a solution for this problem.

I have this HTML:

```
<body>
  <h1>Javascript in the Browser</h1>
  <div id="removeReference">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>This page looks a little sad without any style...</p>
    <button id="styleButton">Apply some style!</button>
  </div>
  <div id="imagePlaceholder">
  </div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

In the JavaScript file, I have a function `stylePage` that is triggered by clicking a button and it adds some style, removes the button itself, and creates a new button.
At this point, I'd like to add an event to this dynamically created new button so that when clicked the function `createImage` is triggered.

I know it's be better to use libraries but this is an attempt at self learning JavaScript.
I thought that maybe it was possible to return the button from `stylePage` and add the event listener to the return value but that didn't work.
Any suggestion is much appreciated, thanks!

```
function stylePage(){
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
  body[0].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(214, 214, 214)";
  body[0].style.color = "#778899";
  body[0].style.fontFamily = "Courier";
  body[0].style.textAlign = "center";
  var remove = document.getElementById("removeReference");
  remove.nextElementSibling.remove();
  var newButton = document.createElement("button");
  var newContent = document.createTextNode("Not enough?");
  newButton.appendChild(newContent);
  document.body.insertBefore(newButton, remove);
};

function createImage(){
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "pepsi_dog_by_werelyokoman.jpg";
  document.getElementById("imagePlaceholder").appendChild(img);
}

var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
button[0].addEventListener("click", stylePage);
//??? reference to newButton ??? .addEventListener("click", createImage);
```

Comment: You may find this article helpful:  https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation

Comment: Thanks for the info on event delegation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to add `.addEventListener` to the end of your `stylePage` function:

```
  var newContent = document.createTextNode("Not enough?");
  newButton.appendChild(newContent);
  document.body.insertBefore(newButton, remove);
  newButton.addEventListener("click", createImage);    
};
```

[JSFiddle demonstrating this](https://jsfiddle.net/f7y9svpf/).

But say you didn't want to do that for some reason -- maybe you don't have control over the function that's dynamically creating your button. In this case you could use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch for changes in the DOM.

You'd do this like so:

```
var target = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if(mutation.addedNodes.length > 0 && mutation.addedNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue == "Not enough?") {
       mutation.addedNodes[0].addEventListener("click", createImage);
    }
  });    
});

var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };
observer.observe(target, config);
```

See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqkw1xaj/).

Answer (score -2):

You can use event delegation:

```
document.querySelector('body').on('click', function() {
    //You need to identify the new elements here......
});
```

I created a jsfiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/huozicheng/zccpxwvL/)

Comment: This doesn't do at all what the OP asked for -- the whole point of the question is identifying the new elements.

Comment: Also, really silly to use `document.querySelector('body')` when `document.body` gets you the body element too.  But, this doesn't even solve the problem.

Comment: The whole point of the question was to ensure a click handler was attached to dynamically created elements. This is exactly what event delegation is meant to handle.